# How can I add Default list in dropdown then use my search input to filter that list in SSRS Report

Tags: dropdown, ssrs-2012, searchable

I've created a dropdown list that is filtered according the value present in a search box .
But the issue is untill I enter the value in Search box the dropdown is in disabled state.
Is there any way that i can get the whole list by default on load and then i use my search box to filter the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple to do. Here's the steps to create a similar report.

If you want to follow exactly, then you will need a copy of the WideWorldImporters sample database as that's what I used as my sample data.

This following report simply lists customers and their phone numbers, the customers listed are based on a drop down list of customers and that drop down list is based on the  contents of a 'search' parameter.

To start, create a new blank report

Add a parameter called `pSearch`, set the `Allow blank value ("")` option `ON`. In the default values tab, select `Specify values`, click `Add` but leave the Value blank. This bit is important...
[image]
[image]

Next, add a dataset called `dsCustomer`. This query will supply the data to the drop down list so we will filter based on the `pSearch` parameter that we just set up.

The dataset query should look something like this.

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName FROM [Sales].[Customers] 
WHERE 
    (CustomerName LIKE '%' + @pSearch + '%'
    OR      
    ISNULL(LEN(@pSearch),0)=0
    )
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

This will return the full list if the parameter is blank or null, otherwise it will return a filtered list.

Next, create a paramater called `pCustomers`, Set `Allow multiple values` to `ON`. Set the available values  to `Get values from a query` and point this to the `dsCustomer` dataset.

[image]
[image]

You can test the parameter now, when the report first opens the customer list will be full but if you type into the search parameter then drop the customer list down again you will see a filtered list.

This may be all you need, I finished the report as follows
Create another dataset called `dsMain`. This will supply the data to the final report table so it will filter based on our pCustomers parameter.

The dataset query will be something like.

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerName, PhoneNumber FROM [Sales].[Customers] 
WHERE CustomerID IN (@pCustomers)
ORDER BY CustomerName
```

Finally I placed a table in the report and bound it to `dsMain`

The final report looks like this then it first opens.

[image]

and if I type `ala` into the seearch parameter and drop the list down again I see this.

**IMPORTANT** Remember that parameter names are Case Sensistive so the name must match exactly with your dataset query.

[image]

Comment: Thanx Alan, for help but one more issue is there this whole system is working fine for me in preview mode but when I deploy this report I always need to enter a space in search box  to enable this dropdown with all instances  .

Comment: try to delete the server copy and redeploy, the defaults are not updated if you redeploy a report.If my answer resolved your issue please mark it as accepted.